# ng-repeat is calling another function more than its objects?

Tags: angularjs

I am having a ng-repeat with one array and three objects within an array.

and I am calling a function from img src="{{}}" which is in ng-repeat.

So as per concept an img src function should get called 3 times (because I have 3 objects in an array), but it gets called 15 times.

```
  <div class="" ng-init="getCurrentModuleId();"> <!-- 1st image row start -->
    <div class="" ng-repeat="obj in courseModuleData" 
      ng-click="getStartFunction($index + 1);">
      <a href="javascript:;" class="hoverStyle">
        <img id="{{$index + 1}}" src="{{getLockPlayImage($index + 1);}}" 
          class="tresure_img">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

js code:-

```
function getLockPlayImage(id) {
    $log.info("Welcome to getLockPlayImage function");
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    el.style.top = $scope.courseModuleData[id - 1].cordinates.x + "px";
    el.style.left = $scope.courseModuleData[id - 1].cordinates.y + "px";
    if (getModuleId.module_id == id) {
      $scope.getImage = "img/start/playbutton_normal.png";
      /*var el =document.getElementById(id);
       el.setAttribute('ng-click', 'startQuestions()');*/
    } else {
      $scope.getImage = "img/start/lock_normal.png";
    }
    return $scope.getImage;
  }

function getCurrentModuleId() {
    var _promiseObject = new promise.Promise();
    $log.info("Welcome to getLock getCurrentModuleId function");

    var getActModule = $scope.startModule();

    getActModule.then(function (result) {

      _promiseObject.done(false, "Downloaded");

      getModuleId = result.rows.item(0);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Note that that function will be called once per array item *per change detection cycle*.

Comment: Please, post your js code so that we can see what is happening to the courseModuleData.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle with your example?